# Pymongo exception handling , unable to resolve errors in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, error-handling

I am not able to perform exception handling it give unable to resolve error in pymongo.

What would be the reason for that , all the documentation i see for pymongo error handling gives the same code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)
try:
    connection = MongoClient()
    db = connection.collection
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure:
    result = {}
    result['success'] = False
    result['error'] = "Db connection Failed"
```

Comment: What's the error are you getting ? what's the expected outcome ?

Comment: Its not capturing the exception . The exception is raised but it is not able to resolve the pymongo.errors, say the errors cannnot be resolved

Comment: What is the exception that is raised?  What is the actual (copy+paste) error output? Your example code above shouldn't raise any connection failure, because there is no cursor execution yet. Please elaborate your problem with reproducible error.

Comment: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.    This the error i get when the server is not running.

Comment: If the`mongod` server is not running, the exact snippet you posted should not return you any error or any exception. This is because there is no cursor being executed. what version is your `pymongo`, `flask-pymongo` and python ?

Comment: flash : 0.11.1, python 2.7,pymongo : 3.3.0

Comment: The question is: What's the generic exception under pymongo.errors to catch all conneciton related errors?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments section of the question, I can say there are two major solutions for that:

1. First see if the `mongod` service is running. If it's not running, start the service by running `mongod`.
2. If it's running, check whether you are allowed to connect to the mongodb instance. If you are not allowed, contact your System/DB admin to whitelist your IP.

The second step is for the users where the users are trying to connect the **remote MongoDB instance instead of their local system**.